# Scripting languages on iOS games

Tags: c++, ios, scripting-language

First of all, there are other topics covering this subject but they were posted before Apple made the latest changes in its licenses this year.

I'm quite confused with Apple's iOS developer agreement license. Does it completely forbid scripting languages on game programming? Even if I don't compile it at runtime and provide all the code within the game package?

I have a game engine written in C++ which provides a scripting layer based on AngelScript used to ease the game logic programming. Is it true that I can't ever publish a game made with it as long as I use AngelScript for game event scripting?

Many game developers put an abstraction layer over their C++ library/engine/framework to ease game development, which doesn't change the fact the the games were actually written in C/C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a scripting language as long as it doesn't download any code. It's not the scripting language apple has a problem with Angry birds for instance uses (**lots**) of Lua code.
[image: Angry Birds Level files]

If though you try downloading code and executing it then Apple will reject your app. Although even this is a gray area. For instance 'when does something become code?'. As an example you can download a new level pack for your game if then level's are defined in XML files.
But say for instance you use your own custom file format rather then XML for greater functionality. At what point does your code stop simply define parts of the game and become code?

Like many regulations there are gray areas even with things apple forbids (downloading code), however you shouldn't have a problem using a scripting language.

Comment: How did you manage to see those files directly on your device?

Comment: @lhf All my devices are jailbroken the instant I get them (allows full control of the device). The app there is called iFile, it's a Finder clone for iOS so you can browse (and edit) the iOS file system.

Answer (score 2):

With Unity out and about on iOS, I have a hard time believing that Apple will enforce this, if they can...

Comment: They would probably open exceptions to Unity and other well known engines and frameworks (like Corona). But how about smaller "in-house" engines like the one we have in my company? Shame on Steve Jobs if they're doing it...

Comment: We have one as well and I doubt we'll be banned for using it either.